# How to read 2 files and write content to another file using a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 2 files which look like this.

file-A

```
Red 
Green 
Blue
Yellow
```

file-B

```
Car
Bus 
Van
Bike
```

I have to write content of them to `file-C` by following the **defined variable**. (Every time file-A and file-B line count will be equal)

expected output:

```
Red Car
Green Bus Green
Blue Blue Blue
Yellow
```

This is what I tried (I must follow this way)

```
mycolor="file-A"
myvehicle=$(cat file-B)

while read -r color
do

  for vehicle in $myvehicle
  do
  
    echo $color $vehicle
    echo $color $vehicle $color
    echo $color $color $color
    echo $color 

    
  done 
     
done <$mycolor > file-C
```

then output I got

```
Red Car
Red Car Red
Red Red Red
Red
Red Bus
Red Bus Red
Red Red Red
Red
Red Van
Red Van Red
Red Red Red
Red
Red Bike
Red Bike Red
Red Red Red
Red
Green Car
Green Car Green
Green Green Green
Green
Green Bus
Green Bus Green
Green Green Green
Green
Green Van
Green Van Green
Green Green Green
Green
Green Bike
Green Bike Green
Green Green Green
Green
Blue Car
Blue Car Blue
Blue Blue Blue
Blue
Blue Bus
Blue Bus Blue
Blue Blue Blue
Blue
Blue Van
Blue Van Blue
Blue Blue Blue
Blue
Blue Bike
Blue Bike Blue
Blue Blue Blue
Blue
Yellow Car
Yellow Car Yellow
Yellow Yellow Yellow
Yellow
Yellow Bus
Yellow Bus Yellow
Yellow Yellow Yellow
Yellow
Yellow Van
Yellow Van Yellow
Yellow Yellow Yellow
Yellow
Yellow Bike
Yellow Bike Yellow
Yellow Yellow Yellow
Yellow
```

Can someone help me to figure out this? Thanks in advance!

Note: I am not allowed to use jq or other languages as JavaScript, Python etc.

Comment: What if there are 10 colours in `file-A`?

Comment: then I have to write all of them in file-C. every time file-A and file-B line count will be equal. then file-B will also have 10 lines.

Comment: What is `defined variable` and what is variable based approach? Can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: "Follow this way" -- we can't answer unless we know what we're allowed to change; and obviously, your code doesn't work, so it can't be followed exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file1.txt` content be

```
Red 
Green 
Blue
Yellow
```

and `file2.txt` content be

```
Car
Bus 
Van
Bike
```

then

```
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[FNR]=$1;next}FNR==1{print arr[1],$1}FNR==2{print arr[2],$1,arr[2]}FNR==3{print arr[3],arr[3],arr[3]}FNR==4{print arr[4]}' file1.txt file2.txt
```

gives output

```
Red Car
Green Bus Green
Blue Blue Blue
Yellow
```

Explanation: `FNR` is number of row inside processed file, `NR` is number of row globally, therefore action with pattern `FNR==NR` is applied solely to 1st file rammed. When processing first file I simply fill array `arr` so that keys are number of lines and values are 1st fields and as I do not want anything else I instruct GNU `AWK` to go to `next` row. When processing further files I print depending on number of row, colour is retrieved from array `arr` using key being same as number of row.

*(tested in GNU Awk 4.0.0)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but according to my scenario I have to use variable base approach (As the way I mentioned in question). this is just an abstract of my scenario. So, I have to follow variable base approach. then I can pass those values Anyware it needed

Comment: @Zero5, what do you even mean by the words "variable based approach"? Be exact and specific. Daweo's approach _does_ use variables -- `arr` is an awk variable -- so we need to understand _exactly_ why one variable-based approach is legal and another is not.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
$ paste -d' ' file-A file-B
Red Car
Green Bus
Blue Van
Yellow Bike
```

But if you insist in using bash variables:

```bash
$ paste file-A file-B | while read -r a b; do printf '%s %s\n' "$a" "$b"; done
Red Car
Green Bus
Blue Van
Yellow Bike
```

Or:

```bash
$ mapfile -t a < file-A
$ mapfile -t b < file-B
$ for (( i=0; i<${#a[@]}; i++ )); do printf '%s %s\n' "${a[i]}" "${b[i]}"; done
Red Car
Green Bus
Blue Van
Yellow Bike
```